# D3js X AXIS time - out of range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, scale

I did a graph where my x-axis is out of the range in svg element.
I am using object structure ProgressGraph to save my options (because of another things...)
I would like to set x-axis to fixed size 720x450, but when I call zoom or I want to translate graph to right / left , the X-axis is going out of the svg element. The x-axis size width is changing from 720 to 920.53 and I do not know why. This width should be fixed to 720px.

Screenshots:
[Good One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWu3D.png) good one before zoom / move to side
[Bad One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQqaf.png) bad one after zoom / move to side

```
graphParams : {
    //whole size
    width : 1050,
    height : 600,
    //svg -g
    svg_width: 720,
    svg_height : 450
 }

    x =  d3.time.scale().domain(ProgressGraph.xAxisDomain).range([0,graphParams.svg_width]);

    xAxis = 
            d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickSize(-graphParams.svg_height)
                .tickPadding(12)       
                .ticks(12);

     yAxis = 
            d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickSize(-graphParams.svg_width);  

    zoom = 
            d3.behavior.zoom()
                .x(x)
                .scaleExtent([1, 32])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select("#projectProgress-graph-div").append("svg")
        .attr("width", graphParams.width)
        .attr("height", graphParams.height)
        .append("g")
            .attr("id", "projectProgress-graph-svg")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (graphMargin.left) + "," + graphMargin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", graphParams.svg_width )          
        .attr("height", graphParams.svg_height);   

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("width",  graphParams..svg_width)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + graphParams.svg_height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
            .attr("dx", "-2em")
            .attr("dy", ".0em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

function zoomed() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
            .attr("dx", "-2em")
            .attr("dy", "0em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sollution is add a svg element befero we add "g element" for x axis

```
        svg.append("svg")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0 , " + graphParams.svg_height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
                .attr("dx", "-2em")
                .attr("dy", ".0em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```